# Django lost migration file

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have a django app connected to postgresql database (RDS instance running on AWS)

Recently, I added new fields to my database tables, but forgot to run `makemigrations` locally and pushed the code to the server. The server went down since changes were not applied, and in order to fix the problem quickly I decided to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` directly in docker container of the application, I thought it would generate migration files, but unfortunately, it didn't. The migration was applied on database level, but there is no migration file of the changes.

When running `python manage.py showmigrations` in the container, it outputs:

```sh
redirect
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_redirect_clicks
 [X] 0003_redirect_name
```

But in database, running `SELECT * FROM django_migrations;` tells that there is one more migration:

```
103 | redirect           | 0004_auto_20210707_2039     | 2021-07-07 14:39:19.058233+00
```

What would you advise? I thought of running `makemigrations` locally, generate the file and push it to vcs, and on the server apply the changes using `migrate --fake`.

I don't know what this does exactly and I am too scared to do it without guidance, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Somebody must have fixed it for you if 0004 is there :) You could just probably ask them to commit that in VCS

Comment: Yeah, that a hairy one. Are you the only one working on this or is someone else?

Comment: @AaronCloud @bdbd
Yes, I am alone working on it. The problem is I ran the `makemigrations` and applied them using `docker-compose run`, it means that changes were applied on the remote database however the file system was not changed somehow

Comment: idk bro. Umm I dont know if doing a local makemigrations would hurt? Then you could push those changes?? But I've never been in this situation, are you live and in production?

Comment: @AaronCloud Yes, everything is working fine, but this is until I make some new changes in db D:

Answer (score 0):

Current solution (not ideal):

I generated the migration file locally, pushed it to VCS, and on remote server i had to unapply all migrations for the app using `python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero` (this caused a data loss for the database tables in the app, so think twice before doing this) and then applied them again, but now with the migration file generated in the 1st step. Everything is back to normal, but obviously there is a better solution

Comment: probably using --fake would be a better option